# Paging order in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure that returns details of business from the database. The page size is 10. I have also paid / not paid business in my database, as defined by a boolean column (`IsPaid` true/false)

I want to show in the first page (or the first 10 pages) just the paid business. And then at the last pages the not paid business.

In my case using this stored procedure below. It returns order of paging per each page. That means if in the first page there is not paid businesses it will return back.

How can I change the order from each page to all the select

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetBusUsingPaginNoTown
    @PageNo int,
    @NoOfRecord int,
    @Id int,
    @TotalRecord int output
AS
    select @TotalRecord = count(*) 
    from BusinessFullData

    select * 
    from 
        (select 
             Row_number() over (order by b.Id ASC) as RowNo,
             b.Ispaid, b.Id, b.name, b.Addess, b.DefaultImage,
             t.TownName, c1.CategoryName AS CatN1, 
             c2.CategoryName AS CatN2, c3.CategoryName AS CatN3 
         from 
             BusinessFullData b 
         left join
             Towns t on b.Town = t.Id 
         left join 
             Categories c1 ON b.cat1 = c1.Id 
         left join
             Categories c2 ON b.cat2 = c2.Id 
         left join
             Categories c3 ON b.cat3 = c3.Id 
         where  
              ((b.IsVisable = 1) 
                AND ((b.Cat1 = @Id) OR (b.Cat2 = @Id) OR (b.Cat3 = @Id)
              )) 
        ) as Tab
  where 
      Tab.RowNo between ((@PageNo - 1) * @NoOfRecord) + 1  
                    and (@PageNo * @NoOfRecord) 
  order by 
      IsPaid desc

  return
```

Comment: "it will return back", what does it means??

Comment: Which version of MS SQL do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`over partition` clause should include the desired order. In your case

```
Row_number() over (order by b.Id ASC) as RowNo,
```

should be replaced with

```
Row_number() over (order by b.isPaid ASC) as RowNo,
```

Hope this helps. This is all I can see for now, unless you describe your question in a clearer way...